Cant update iPhone via FInder on M3 Mac
I can't update my iPhone like I usually do. When I check for updates in finder for my connected iPhone 15 Pro it tells me:

This version of the iPhone software (17.7.1) is the current version.

This is not true for iOS 17, also it does not offer me to update to iOS 18.
I have updated macOS to 15.1.1 (24B91), but Finder still tells me there are no update for my iPhone.
What can I do to fix the Finder?

The same happened to me recently. The only way was an update over the air in iOS.
